# Как сделать obfuscate имен классов с react и webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, обфускация

Я создал react-приложение с помощью `create-react-app`.

Как я могу обфускцировать классы?

Я нашел [эту статью](https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda), но я не понимаю, как это сделать.

[Ссылка на мое приложение](https://github.com/netBriler/react-notes)

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я должен сделать чтобы обфускцировать классы?

Answer (score 2):

Это делается в настройка `css-loader` в файле конфигурации Webpack (webpack.config.js).

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            // ... другие лоадеры
            {
                loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
                options: {
                    modules: {
                        localIdentName: "[hash:base64]"
                    }
            }
            // ... другие лоадеры
        ],
        include: /\.module\.css$/
        }
    ]
}
```

Изменяя значение `localIdentName` можно "собрать" требуемый конечный результат.

Например если класс называется `example-name` то при настройках:

```
localIdentName: "[hash:base64]" // e2YeMBJwo5VHqgN5ViGVsK9
localIdentName: "[local]__[hash:base64]" // example-name__e2YeMBJwo5VHqgN5ViGVsK9
```

Имейте ввиду что согласно правилам naming'a имена классов не должны начинаться с цифр.

`create-react-app` не предоставляет доступ к файлу конфигурации, для этого придется выполнить команду `eject` (действие необратимо).

Answer (score 0):

Будут classNames типа: *a_a, a_b, a_c* .... и так далее.

1. Выполнить eject
2. Установить `incstr`
3. Создать файл `getScopedName.js` в папке `config`.

```js
const incstr = require('incstr');
const createUniqueIdGenerator = () => {
  const uniqIds = {};
  const generateNextId = incstr.idGenerator({
    alphabet: 'abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  });
  return (name) => {
    if (!uniqIds[name]) {
      uniqIds[name] = generateNextId();
    }
    return uniqIds[name];
  };
};
const localNameIdGenerator = createUniqueIdGenerator();
const componentNameIdGenerator = createUniqueIdGenerator();
module.exports = (localName, resourcePath) => {
  const componentName = resourcePath
    .split('/')
    .slice(-2, -1)[0];
  const localId = localNameIdGenerator(localName);
  const componentId = componentNameIdGenerator(componentName);
  return `${componentId}_${localId}`;
};
```

4. Открыть `webpack.config.js` и добавить:

```js
const getScopedName = require('./getScopedName')
```

5. Найти секцию на ~445-460 строках и привести к этому виду:

```js
{
  test: cssModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
    modules: {
      ...(isEnvDevelopment ? {
        localIdentName: '[path]_[name]_[local]',
      } : {
       getLocalIdent: (context, localIdentName, localName) => (
         getScopedName(localName, context.resourcePath)
       ),
      })
     },
  }),
}
```

Готово :)